# Which of the following will give a remainder of 1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Which of the following will give a remainder of $1$ ?

$1$. $2^{100}$ divided by $7$

$2$. $2^{110}$ divided by $11$

$3$. $3^{140}$ divided by $11$

$4$. $12^{112}$ divided by $113$

Could someone tell me the approach to solve this question other than binomial theorem?

Comment: [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem)?  E.g. $2^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$ so $2^{110}\equiv (2^{10})^{11}\equiv 1^{11}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$

Comment: @user236182 leave some for him to do.  One example should have sufficed.

Answer (score 2):

[Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem) states:

> If $p$ is prime, then $a^p\equiv a\pmod{p}$ for every integer $a$

In the special case that $a\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ we have that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$

Notice that each number you are dividing by above is prime, so the theorem is directly applicable in each case.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the first three:

- $\color\red{2^3}\equiv\color\red{1}\pmod{7}\implies2^{100}\equiv2^{3\cdot33+1}\equiv(\color\red{2^3})^{33}\cdot2\equiv\color\red{1}^{33}\cdot2\equiv2\pmod{7}$
- $\color\red{2^5}\equiv\color\red{-1}\pmod{11}\implies2^{110}\equiv2^{5\cdot22}\equiv(\color\red{2^5})^{22}\equiv(\color\red{-1})^{22}\equiv1\pmod{11}$
- $\color\red{3^5}\equiv\color\red{1}\pmod{11}\implies3^{140}\equiv3^{5\cdot28}\equiv(\color\red{3^5})^{28}\equiv\color\red{1}^{28}\equiv1\pmod{11}$